# How to avoid duplicating routes for user edit page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, admin

I'm making a simple application which have only two kind of users: Admin and SimpleUser. I want my Gemfile to containt as little gems as possible without any helpers such as 'devise'.

I tried to create a custom controller for handling user profile update, but as far as I know it's not a RESTful approach which is not meant that user parameters be handling by other controller.

So, what profiles should do:

SimpleUser:

> 1. get a url **localhost:XXXX/profile** for editing profile settings
> 2. not be able to get any other routes for editing page such as "/users/7/edit" even if he has id 7
> 3. not be able to edit any other pages via "/users/:id/edit"

Admin:

> 1. get a url **localhost:XXXX/profile** for editing personal profile settings
> 2. get a url for editing any user via "/users/:id/edit"

Right now I've achieved all Admin requirements and only first and third for SimpleUser. How can I reject to give user "/user/user_id/edit" path but still be able to give him "/profile", is it possible without handling and redirecting url?

P.S I'm not asking for a piece of code, I just wanna know possible options how it's done with ruby on rails

Answer (score 0):

You need a `before_action` on your `UsersController` to check if the user is a regular user, if so redirect her to `/profile`. Assuming `/profile` is mapped to `show` action:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_user, except: [:show]

  private
    def check_user
      redirect_to @user unless @user.admin?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set routes.rb as:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end

resource :user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
```

Do a `rake routes` in console to check that as admin you can access to all these actions (note the **:id** parameter):

```
        Prefix  Verb    URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
   admin_users   GET    /admin/users(.:format)           admin/users#index
                POST    /admin/users(.:format)           admin/users#create
 new_admin_user  GET    /admin/users/new(.:format)       admin/users#new
edit_admin_user  GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)  admin/users#edit
     admin_user  GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)       admin/users#show
               PATCH    /admin/users/:id(.:format)       admin/users#update
                 PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)       admin/users#update
              DELETE    /admin/users/:id(.:format)       admin/users#destroy
```

While the user can only (note there is no :id):

```
   Prefix  Verb    URI Pattern              Controller#Action
edit_user   GET    /user/edit(.:format)     users#edit
     user   GET    /user(.:format)          users#show
          PATCH    /user(.:format)          users#update
            PUT    /user(.:format)          users#update
```

So you have different controllers for admin and for user.